# how to call connection in class functions

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

I establish connection in `__construct()` it is proper working but when I calling `this->con` variable in other function of class. it is not working.
I am inserting data in database but data not inserting into database while it's printing correct query in `insertUserData()`.

```
Class RP_Common {

    private $_host = 'localhost';
    private $_username = 'root';
    private $_password = '12345';
    private $_database = 'shipment';

    protected $con;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if (!isset($this->con)) {

            $this->con = new mysqli($this->_host, $this->_username, $this->_password, $this->_database);

            if (!$this->con) {
                echo 'Cannot connect to database server';
                exit;
            }            
        }    

        return $this->con;
    }

    /**

    for inserting user_data
    */

    public function insertUserData($username,$usermobile,$useremail,$userpassword){

        //echo $this->con;

         echo $query="insert into user_table(user_name,user_mobile,user_email,user_password) values('$username',$usermobile,$useremail,$userpassword) ";

        $res=mysqli_query($this->con,$query);

        if($res){
            echo "data inserted successfully";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use prepared statements to avoid the pesky quoting issues.

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO user_table(user_name, user_mobile, user_email,user_password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $usermobile, $useremail,$userpassword);
if($stmt->execute() === true){
 echo 'Data Successfully saved';
}
```

Also do not save passwords in plaintext, it is highly unsafe. Use PHP's `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Answer (score -1):

You need a space after `user_table` and `values`

```
INSERT INTO user_table (user_name,user_mobile,user_email,user_password) values ('$username',$usermobile,$useremail,$userpassword);
```

To see what went wrong with the query, you can use `mysqli_error($conn)`

```
if($res){
  echo "data inserted successfully";
}else{
  echo mysqli_error($this->con);
}
```